# Unable to connect to ports via Linux but can with Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, firewall, port

My company recently moved providers and in doing so, machines now require a certificate to access websites. I'm not sure if this is the cause but I figured I should mention this anyway. Before the move, I was able to SSH into my server with no problem, from any operating system. Now, I can only SSH via my Windows 10 virtual machine (both machines are on the office network) but I cannot from my Arch machine. It would appear that I am able to ping ports 443 and 80 via a Linux terminal but I am unable to ping any other open ports that I know are open since I'm able to ping them from command prompt in Windows.

The certificate file that I'm thinking might be the cause comes as a PKCS12 file which I've extracted the data from and placed in `/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/tls-ca-bundle.pem` as well as `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

With that being said, unless this certificate is not installed properly, it should work, right? I've tried a traceroute from both my Arch machine and Windows machine with the following results.

Linux

```
hayden@workbox ~ sudo nmap -Pn --traceroute -p 22 aa.aa.aa.aa

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-05 11:57 GMT
Nmap scan report for aa.aa.aa.aa
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

TRACEROUTE (using proto 1/icmp)
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.46 ms bb.bb.bb.bb
2   1.40 ms cc.cc.cc.cc
3   2.24 ms dd.dd.dd.dd
4   ... 30

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 16.27 seconds
```

Windows

```
C:\Windows\system32>nmap -Pn --traceroute -p 22 aa.aa.aa.aa

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-05 12:02 GMT Standard Time
Nmap scan report for aa.aa.aa.aa
Host is up (0.025s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

TRACEROUTE (using port 22/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   0.00 ms  bb.bb.bb.bb
2   2.00 ms  cc.cc.cc.cc
3   2.00 ms  dd.dd.dd.dd
4   ... 13
14  28.00 ms aa.aa.aa.aa

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.30 seconds
```

I've called up the provider we are with and they are certain this is not a firewall problem; they can actually see outbound traffic trying to get through to port 22 no matter what system I use which led me to believe it could be the server I am trying to connect to so I logged traffic trying to connect via port 22. What do you know, the requests are landing on the server but they're just not coming back for some reason.

```
hayden@serverbox:~$ sudo tail -1 /var/log/syslog
Feb  5 12:08:34 localhost kernel: [936377.791850] New ConnectionIN=ens192 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:37:1b:25:00:50:56:8e:7f:8f:08:00 SRC=ee.ee.ee.ee DST=aa.aa.aa.aa LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=13193 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54482 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Anything on ports other than 443 and 80, get stuck at dd.dd.dd.dd if I am requesting from my Linux machine which leads me to believe that perhaps I haven't actually installed this certificate properly. My question here is: what am I doing wrong? The firewall on my server is fine - it worked flawlessly before we switched providers. The provider we've moved to won't help because it's not in their scope but they were kind enough to investigate a little anyway, ultimately concluding it's not a problem with their firewall. I don't have much networking experience if I'm honest so it would be helpful for some indicators/pointers on how to further investigate this if no answers can be found here.

The three systems mentioned:

- Workbox: Arch 4.14.10
- Virtual machine: Windows 10
- Serverbox: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial)

Comment: Could you post the output of "iptables-save" on your serverbox?
Also, is "ee.ee.ee.ee" an IP that your server can route back to? (What is the output of "ip r s"?)

It is possible that your ports 443 and 80 are going through a transparent proxy, and that there is no working SNAT on your network for port 22.

Comment: # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Feb  7 10:06:46 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2054982:1232398997]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2065672:1638072451]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection" --log-level 1
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  7 10:06:46 2018

Comment: default via 10.255.255.1 dev ens192
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0
10.8.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1
10.255.255.1 dev ens192  scope link

Comment: I can resolve ee.ee.ee.ee but it times out so perhaps there is actually a problem with data coming back... I tried tracerouting to it with port 80 and it makes 8 jumps before timing out